# Bar chart Opportunities owned by current user vs team

Tags: reporting, opportunity, dashboard, ownership

I would like to have on a dashboard bar chart for each Opportunity stage sum of the amounts of the Opportunities owned by the current user and stacked above it the sum of the amounts of the Opportunities owned by the other users in the current user team.

Is there any way to do this ? I have created a summary report on the Opportunities grouped by stage and Opportunity owner but I don't see how to extract the splitted sum of amounts